# Referencing my keystore file in java code

Tags: java

I am trying to connect a keystore i created and imported some certificates into in my code.

This is code snippet

```
if(inputStream  == null){
             inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resource/text.jks");
             socket=sslConnect.sslSocket("00.000.000.000", 9102, "rogue1", "6000", inputStream); 
            }
```

My project is located in `C:\`

This is the path `C:\pdsl\src\pdlsipay`

Inside pdlsipay that's where i have `file.java` with the snippet above.

The folder resource can be found in `c:\pdlsipay`

Inside the folder resource is where you will find text.jks

How can i read the `text.jks` file in this line

`getResourceAsStream("resource/text.jks");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getResourceAsStream is specifically for accessing resources that are on your application's classpath, so you would need to include C:\pdlsiplay in the classpath.

Alternatively, you can avoid getResourceAsStream and read the data directly:

```
File keystoreFile = new File("C:/pdlsipay/resource/text.jks");
FileInputStream keystoreData = new FileImportStream(keystoreFile);
socket=sslConnect.sslSocket("00.000.000.000", 9102, "rogue1", "6000", keystoreData);
```